# What typedef for a static multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, typedef

I have a static 3D array of int. I can declare it this way:

```
int my_array[X_MAX][Y_MAX][Z_MAX];
```

However, this type is used for different purposes in my program, and I'd like to create typedefs to differentiate the usages and make my program easier to read.

Problem is... I don't know how to create these typedefs. `typedef int[X_MAX][Y_MAX][Z_MAX] my_typedef;` was my first and only guess. It doesn't compile. Do you know if there is a way to do what I want? (I mean, with no dynamically-allocated array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef int my_typedef[X_MAX][Y_MAX][Z_MAX];
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine for variables. I'd just like to point out that it does not work for a function declaration. That's logical, since a function can't return an array and must return a pointer. However the typedef "hides" the fact that it's an array, so I made the error several times before realizing it ^^

Comment: You can use it for function parameters, but not return types: `int f(my_typedef a)`.